# how to write a function in haskell which inserts space after every character of String

Tags: haskell

i want to implemet a method in haskeel which should add space after every char of string passed to that method but not after the last char of the string
 for example

```
Main> insertSpace "This is world"
"T h i s  i s  w o r l d"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could write this by hand through explicit recursion.

```
insertSpace :: String -> String
insertSpace []     = []
insertSpace (x:[]) = x  -- you need this to keep from adding a space at the end
insertSpace (x:xs) = x:' ':(insertSpace xs)
```

but there is a stdlib function for this in `Data.List` -- `intersperse`.

```
import Data.List (intersperse)

insertSpace :: String -> String
insertSpace = intersperse ' '
```

This is the first result when you search [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) for `Char -> String -> String`.